# Exposed Filter using values in a field

Tags: views

Trying to build an exposed filter for a drupal views table that will allow me to select from a list of values that are found in a specific field. I've created my own views module to allow me to build this view from a custom table that I've created in my db.

For the more visual:

[image: Table View]

I'd like the filter to populate from the values in the Counselor field and allow this user to select from this list so any time a new Counselor is added to the db they will be included for this filter.  Is this possible?

I'm using D7.